# How to retain annotation of default method of interface after implementing and overriding said method

Tags: java, annotations, java-stream, overriding

When I am overriding a default method of an interface which is annotated, the annotation is removed from the child method. I want to retain the annotation in the child even when the method is overridden. What is the reason for it getting removed?

**MyAnnotation.java**

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface MyAnnotation {
    public String config();
}
```

**MyInterface,java**

```
public interface MyInterface {
    
    @MyAnnotation(config="myConfig")
    public default String getMyVal() {
        return null;
    }
    
    @MyAnnotation(config="myConfig")
    public default String getMyVal2() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**MyModel.java**

```
public class MyModel implements MyInterface {
    @Override
    public String getMyVal() {
        return "MyVal";
    }
}
```

**MainRunner.java**

```
public class MainRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Arrays.stream(MyModel.class.getMethods()).forEach(
                method -> Arrays.stream(method.getAnnotations()).forEach(ann-> System.out.println(method + " --- " + ann.annotationType()))
                );
    }
}
```

***Output***

> public native int java.lang.Object.hashCode() --- interface
> jdk.internal.HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate public final native
> java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass() --- interface
> jdk.internal.HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate public final native void
> java.lang.Object.notify() --- interface
> jdk.internal.HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate public final native void
> java.lang.Object.notifyAll() --- interface
> jdk.internal.HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate public default java.lang.String
> com.javaconcepts.annotations.MyInterface.getMyVal2() --- interface
> com.javaconcepts.annotations.MyAnnotation

Appreciate the help. Thanks.

PS: I tried searching but having overridden and annotations in the search gave results for overridden annotation.

Comment: Member annotations are not inherited. Considering that a method can override or implement more than one method, that’s a sensible language design decision. What’s stopping you from using `MyInterface.class.getMethods()` instead of `MyModel.class.getMethods()`? Looks much like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)…

Comment: @Holger I want to know exactly which methods of MyInterface have been overridden by MyModel. This is to add logic based on the methods of MyInterface overridden. Example: Suppose MyInterface is having 5 methods and MyModel1 overrides 2 of them, MyModel2 overrides 3 of them. I want to know exactly which methods are overridden by which class(MyModel1 or MyModel2). I was thinking to add an annotation which will differentiate the methods and use getDeclaredClass() method to identify the class which overrides those methods.

Comment: I can directly check the getDeclaredClass() of all the methods but this will result in me having to maintain another map or enum for methods of the interface. Annotations will just allow me to add a new method with my annotation to the interface and no other change will be required.

Comment: Why would you have to maintain a map? `MyInterface.class.getDeclaredMethods()` gives you precisely the methods declared by the interface. In contrast, the annotation doesn’t prove that the method has been declared by the interface. The class `MyModel` could declare an arbitrary method, not implementing an interface, and add the annotation to it.

Comment: I want to send some info using the annotations. Like a value assoicated with the method.   I will need to maintain a map to get that value for the corresponding method if it is overridden by the child.

Comment: “I will need to…” is a contradicting in itself. You don’t need a map. Perhaps, you can use a map in a way that it simplifies what you are doing, but it is no required part of the logic. There is only one way to find out whether a method has been declared by the interface: query the interface, i.e. via `getDeclaredMethod[s]`. When you do that, the annotation and its value(s) comes for free.